# associate customer to available websites

Tags: php, magento

I'd created 3 websites in *magento admin* but they do not have different urls for now.

The thing I want to do is, on the registration page I'd added one more field for `website` where I'd programmatically created a select box as:

```
<select name="website">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <?php
        $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $web) {
            echo "<option value='" . $web->getId() . "'>" .
                     $web->getName() . "</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Now when the user submits this form, based on the chosen `website` he need to be associated with it.

For this I'd already overriden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `createPostAction()` but I'm wondering how do I assign this `website id` as in `parent::createPostAction()` there's too much abstraction.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[finally found this answer helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309714/725306). But I'd made some changes in the observer where I do needed to get the `website id` selected by the customer.

**Here's the code from my observer**

```
public function setWebsiteId($object) {
    //getting website_id from user selection
    $webid = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()
            ->getParam('website_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    $customer = $object->getCustomer();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($webid);
    return $this;
}
```

The event need to be handled is: `customer_register_success`

**Revision**

The above code works fine but the problem with the above implementation was, if a user is already registered in the current website then from the current website he will not be able to register in the other website. To solve this problem I'd overridden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `createPostAction()`

```
public function createPostAction() {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if (isset($post['website_id'])) {
        $webid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website_id');
        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($webid);
        Mage::register('current_customer', $customer); //this is the important line here
    }
    parent::createPostAction();
}
```

If I'm not doing this `Mage::register('current_customer', $customer);` then the parent `createPostAction()` will again fetch customer object as `$customer = $this->_getCustomer();` and loss `website_id` which I had set in there previously.

Comment: This seems to work okay, but the problem is afterwards the customer is forwarded to the account welcome screen and they are not logged in. Name and email info is missing also. If you click on any account links you're booted to login.

Comment: @Corgalore: the above code is just supposed to associate a customer to magento's available websites. there is no code for redirecting customer to welcome screen or login. probably something getting wrong which is preventing user from login. check in admin whether customer is created or not? I recommend to use second approach by overriding the controller instead of observer.

Answer (score 1):

Try naming your select `website_id` instead of `website`.
The `website_id` is has a backend model `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Attribute_Backend_Website` that is called when saving the customer entity.
So each time you call `$customer->save` this is called

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    if ($object->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (!$object->hasData('website_id')) {
        $object->setData('website_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This means that if the customer does not have a website_id, the current website id is assigned.

Comment: still getting `Main Website` as the associated website

Comment: I'd tried renaming my `<select>` to `website_id` instead it was being added to `Main Website`. its not added to `object` being received here.

Comment: you were right but there was missing something... I'd updated my answer