# redirect customer to associated website on successful registration

Tags: php, magento

I'd been working on a module where customer choose at the time of registration for which website he need to register. So far I'd done it working. A [quick reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21729573/725306) to that. On successful registration the customer is being redirected to `customer/account/` in the current website regardless of which website he chosen. But I need him to be redirected to that particular website for which he had registered.

So far I'd tried overriding the `Customer/AccountController`'s `_welcomeCustomer()`:

```
protected function _welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConformed = false) {
    $webid = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    $successurl = parent::_welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConfirmed);
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == $webid) {
        return $successurl;
    } else {
        return Mage::app()->getWebsite($webid)->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl() . 'customer/account/index';
    }
}
```

But instead of redirecting the customer to associated website it being redirected to home page of the current website. Any help? How could it be done? or this happening so?

Comment: I suggest you [Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) StackExchange is better place for this one.

Comment: I can't. I guess a mod can. Or else just delete this one & asked a new one over there.

Comment: @Rikesh: if you can answer. I'd posted it [there](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15045/4426)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this <del>[auto-login module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/313180/)</del> helped me to achieve what I'm looking for.
Rest of the thing I've done to make it work proper is:

Overridden the `Customer/AccountController`'s `_welcomeCustomer()`

```
protected function _welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConformed = false) {
    $webid = $customer->getWebsiteId();
    $encpw = ;//get customer password and encrypt it;
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == $webid) {
        return parent::_welcomeCustomer($customer, $isJustConfirmed);
    } else {
        $redr = Mage::app()->getWebsite($webid)->getDefaultStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl() . 'customer/account/autoLogin/'
                . 'user/' . $customer->getEmail() . '/pwd/' . $encpw .
                '/';
        return $redr;
    }
}
```

One more thing might needed to be changed in `_successProcessRegistration()` is to replace `$this->_redirectSuccess($url);` with `$this->_redirectUrl($url);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the store code as a GET parameter to the URL (___store=xyz).
Probably you will also need to add the Session ID to the url (param name: SID).

Comment: how will the url supposed to look like? do i add encrypted session id?

Comment: i tried it like `http://mymagento.com/store/index.php/customer/account/index/?SID=<encrypted_sid>&___store=<default_store_code>` but still being redirected to login page